# how to fire a script when network interface goes down

Tags: networking, systemd

On my embedded linux board I am using systemd-networkd to manage my network interface configurations.
I need to fire some one shot scripts which will start/stop my custom application when the network interface comes up and goes down.
I have found [networkd dispatcher](https://github.com/craftyguy/networkd-dispatcher) which does what I am looking for but I am not sure how resource intensive it is and would it be a optimal solution for my need.

Is there any alternative to this ?

I am aware of systemd-network-wait-online which can be used to wait till network is up but as per my knowledge systemd target dependency is limited to boot-up sequence.

Comment: This reads like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  Your host is likely to be connected to a switch, and losing this one link is just one of many possible ways to get disconnected from other hosts.  IOW the up/down status of this *local* link is not as informative as you seem to think.  That's why there are higher-level constructs such as [keep-alive messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I have currently handled the  problem is by introducing my own script which runs in the background and observes the network status and link status.
Its starts and stops a systemd target when the network goes offline or comes back online. The application depend on this specific target for network dependency.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've written a bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect. You can adapt it for your use case.